# Selecting a single outputted record that was generated through a while loop reflecting info from a table in my DB

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to add in the ability to edit data that is outputted from my db. It is outputted via while loop into a table I created. I will be adding a button/link in the while loop that will show up at the end of every record and when you click that button/link it will give the option to edit the information in that record. Then submit it and the new information is saved and displayed.

How would I make this work for a single record in my outputted data? If I add the link/button inside of the while loop, would it recognize that it is for that particular record?I would put the button after the `echo $row['description']` loop.

If this is possible how would I capture that single record to display in the page I link the button to?

```
<table class="tableproduct">
                <tr>
                    <th class="thproduct">Product ID</th>
                    <th class="thproduct">Product Name</th>
                    <th class="thproduct">Price</th>
                    <th class="thproduct">Category</th>
                    <th class="thproduct">Description</th>
                </tr>   


 <?php                  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) : ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['product_id'];       ?> </td>
                        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td> 
                        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['price']; ?> </td>
                        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['category']; ?> </td>
                        <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['description']; ?> </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>    
<?php   endwhile; ?>
```

NEW CODE

## Manage Users

```
 <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bfb");
$q = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users");
 ?>                 
                    <table class="tableproduct">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="thproduct">ID</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">First Name</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Last Name</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Email</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Username</th>
                            <th class="thproduct">Group</th>
                        </tr>   
   <?php                    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) : ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['id']; ?> </td>
                            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> </td> 
                            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?> </td>
                            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['email']; ?> </td>
                            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['username']; ?> </td>
                            <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['group']; ?> </td>
                            <td class="tdproduct"><a href='editusers.phpid'='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
                        </tr>

   <?php    endwhile; ?>
                    </table>
```

Editusers.php

```
    <div class="whitepage">
            <div class="content">
                <form action="" method="post">
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                            <input type="text" name="firstname" class="inputbar" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->firstname); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="lastname" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->lastname); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" class="inputbaremail" name="email" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->email); ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="inputbar" name="username" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->username); ?>" required>
                        </div>  

                            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
                            <label for="signinButton">
                                <input type="submit" id="signinButton" value="Update">
                            </label>
                    </form>

  <?php
 $_GET['id'];
  ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) : ?>
   <tr>
     <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['product_id']; ?> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['name']; ?> </td> 
     <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['price']; ?> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['category']; ?> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><?php echo $row['description']; ?> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><a href='edit.php?product_id='<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>'>EDIT</a></td>
   </tr>
<?php   endwhile; ?>
 </table>
```

So you need to create another `edit.php` file and read `product_id` from `$_GET('product_id')` there.

Don't forget to move `</table>` outside the loop :-)

**EDIT 1** In your edit.php you will change the query and:

```
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) { ?>
   <tr>
     <form action='save.php'>
     <td class="tdproduct"><input name="product_id" value="<?php echo $row['product_id']; ?>" /> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><input name="product_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" /> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><input name="price" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>" /> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><input name="category" value="<?php echo $row['category']; ?>" /> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><input name="description" value="<?php echo $row['description']; ?>" /> </td>
     <td class="tdproduct"><input type="submit" value="SAVE" /></td>
     </form>
   </tr>
<?php  }; ?>
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help. What exactly do you mean by this? .... edit.php file and read product_id from $_GET('product_id') there.

Comment: hey Alex, how would I read product_id from $GET('product_id'). I'm not sure how to integrate the two. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, I created another file. Except I made it editproducts.php. I changed the code you created to reflect the different file name though. So it says <a href='editproducts.php?product_id='<?php

Comment: Would I add this type of function inside of my edit file?        myFunction(){
   ob_start();
   include('myfilewiththetableinit.php');
   $page = ob_get_clean();
   return $page;
}

Comment: I see no reason to do that. what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I am wanting to be able to click the edit button in the table I created. Then when clicking edit that take me to the edit.php file and then I am will be adding in the ability to change/edit that record that I clicked. So essentially I want that records data to show up when clicking edit. But only that record.

Comment: My edit page code just has the basic page format with my header, footer, etc. I am not sure how to gather information from just the record I clicked edit on the previous page and echo it to that page. Then only escape that records information.

Comment: do the same way you did current page that is just the query that makes difference adn we will modify table rows format

Comment: Sorry I'm not too sure what you mean. When I click on edit, I will be putting in different input fields. In those input fields I will be escaping the record data and create the ability to update that to the db that way. How would I change the query?

Comment: what is your current page code? do the copy and rename to edit.php and show me the code

Comment: I added my code to my original question for a different page, but it has basically the exact same table(just different subjects). The page is admincustomers.php.... I then have it going to editusers.php.... So you want me to copy the same table that is inside of admincustomers.php into the editusers.php file?

Comment: nothing new, you had never post your code of `edit.php`

Comment: Ok, I have added editusers.php to my orginal answer at the bottom. I basically just need to it recognize that when I select edit on the previous page that it gathers that users or products id and gathers that info. In my edit page I'm going to have a lot more inputs and information. The previous page with table is a summary